# Remove parent items from a list when having chilid items by checking parent IDs of the list c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which has both parent and child service items. I need to get all the parent services which does not have any child service and all the child services into one list. That means I want to remove the items which has child items. How can I do this using LINQ? My list is something like below

```
public class Service
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Parent { get; set; }
 }

 var ServiceList = new List<Service>();
 ServiceList.Add(new Service() { Id = 1, Name = "service 1", Parent= -1 });
 ServiceList.Add(new Service() { Id = 2, Name = "service 2", Parent= -1 });
 ServiceList.Add(new Service() { Id = 3, Name = "service 3", Parent= -1 });
 ServiceList.Add(new Service() { Id = 4, Name = "Service 4", Parent= 2 });
 ServiceList.Add(new Service() { Id = 5, Name = "Service 5", Parent = 2 });
 ServiceList.Add(new Service() { Id = 6, Name = "Service 6", Parent = -1 })
```

With the above list I want to remove "Service 2" from the list. Since there are two child services for that parent service. I want to keep all other parent and child services in the list.

Comment: You should be able to do that by selecting all services where the service Id doesn't equal Any parent Id. With `Any` being the linq method you should be looking at.

Comment: @melkisadek did you mean something like this ServiceList.RemoveAll(p => p.ID == p.ParentID).ToList();

Comment: I'm assuming you want to remove the service that has id 2 and all child services for that service: ServiceList.RemoveAll(p => p.ParentID == 2 || p.Id ==2)

Comment: @heap1 Yes. But I don't know whether the ID will be 2 or something else. I need to remove the items bu checking property values only.

Comment: So what determines what services you want to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter every service, Where the Id of the service is Not the parent id of Any other service in the collection.

```
var result = ServiceList
    .Where(parent => !ServiceList.Any(child => parent.Id == child.Parent));
```